# С помощью цикла нужно сделать проверку на простое число

Tags: javascript

Проблема заключается в том что проверку проходят не только простые числа. К примеру число 8 тоже проходит проверку цикла но оно не является простым  так как оно может делится на другие числа(также 1 и самого себя) без остатка, и 7 тоже проходит проверку хотя оно уже является простым, оно больше единицы и может делится только само на себя без остатка.

```js
const numberFourthTask = 7;
for (let i = 1; i <= numberFourthTask; i++) {
    if (1 < numberFourthTask && numberFourthTask % i === 0) {
        console.log('Является простым')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что у вас за логика используется?

Если **хотя бы один** остаток от деления numberFourthTask на меньшие числа равен нулю, то оно **не простое**.

P.S. Достаточно проверять числа до корня из numberFourthTask

```js
      const numberFourthTask = 7;
      let i = 2;
      let flag = 1;
      const sq = Math.sqrt(numberFourthTask);
      while (i <= sq) {
        if (numberFourthTask % i === 0) {
          flag = 0;
          console.log ('Число составное!');
          break;
        }
        i +=1;
      }
      if (flag == 1)  
       console.log ('Простое число');
```

проще сделать отдельной функцией, тогда флаг не понадобится

Comment: Если можете объясните пожалуйста в чем заключается у меня проблема ?

Comment: В том, что ваша проверка  показывает, что число НЕ простое, а выводите вы, что оно простое.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста а как корректно указать проверку чтобы показывалось уведомление только для простых чисел.

Comment: @Dmitriy Yaroshchuk Разобрались?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста а для чего вы используете переменную flag ?

Comment: Нужно убедиться, что ни одно число не является делителем. Если хоть одно является - флаг сбрасывается.